# Can I call prop.setValue in a single line?

Tags: c#, enums

Is it possible to call this "setvalue()" method in a single line?

```
var genderProp = inj.GetType().GetProperty("gender");
genderProp.SetValue(inj, Enum.Parse(genderProp.PropertyType, "Male"), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as following, but not sure how it would help in making the code more readable.

```
inj.GetType().GetProperty("gender").SetValue(inj, Enum.Parse(inj.GetType().GetProperty("gender").PropertyType, "Male"), null);
```

An alternative approach would be

```
inj.GetType().InvokeMember("gender",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
    Type.DefaultBinder, inj, new[]{Enum.Parse(inj.GetType().GetProperty("gender").PropertyType, "Male")});
```

Personally, i would prefer the two line code.

Comment: I should alter my post and say without calling getproperty twice.

Comment: your alternative approach seems pretty long and convoluted

Comment: @user1186050 that's because you want refuctor your code :) What you have is pretty readable... and there is generally no syntax sugar for reflection to make it shorter... Also if `dynamic` is an option for you than it would be more compact (I've added that option to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you going for single statement but still try to not call `GetProperty` twice you can use C# variant of [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
((Action<PropertyInfo, object>)
   ((genderProp,x) => 
         genderProp.SetValue(x, Enum.Parse(genderProp.PropertyType, "Male"), null)))
    (inj.GetType().GetProperty("gender"), inj);
```

I would not recommend doing it in real code, but somewhat valuable technique if you want some complicated statements reusing same parameter in LINQPad for example.

For real code consider `dynamic` - which will properly handle all reflection (including needed caching):

```
  ((dynamic)inj).gender =  Enum.Parse(genderProp.PropertyType, "Male");
```